# Three.js/WebGL: Use black and white scene as a mask to make an outline

Tags: three.js, webgl, outline

I'm having trouble with an effect I'm trying to achieve in Three.js. I want to get outlines in my game, but I also want them to be affected by depth. I am using 3 scenes (one which has the main model, one which has the mask, and one which has coloured models for the outlines).

My mask looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it consists of black, white, and alpha.

Now, what I want is for every instance of alpha and black in the mask to cut out my image, while every instance of white to be shown.

Unfortunately, with my current stencil script, only the alpha gets cut out:

```
var gl = this.renderer.domElement.getContext('webgl') || this.renderer.domElement.getContext('experimental-webgl');

        // Make the entire stencil solid first.
        gl.clearStencil(1);
        gl.clear(gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Whenever the value of a pixel is 1 in the mask, make that pixel = 0 in the stencil.
        // 0xFF is the identifier I think.
        gl.stencilFunc(gl.ALWAYS, 0, 0xFF);
        gl.stencilOp(gl.REPLACE, gl.GL_REPLACE, gl.GL_REPLACE);

        // Disable color (u can also disable here the depth buffers)
        gl.colorMask(false, false, false, false);

        // Write to stencil
        gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);

        gl.stencilMask(0xFF);

        // Mask (Create a stencil that we render the next pass into)
        this.renderer.render(this.sceneMask, this.camera);

        // Wherever the stencil is = 1, show the model.
        gl.stencilFunc(gl.EQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
        gl.stencilOp(gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP);

        // Enable color
        gl.colorMask(true, true, true, true);

        // Clear depth buffer (seems important)
        this.renderer.clearDepth();
        this.renderer.render(this.sceneOutline, this.camera);

        // Disable stencil test;
        gl.disable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
```

What do I need to do to have both cut out? I don't really understand everything about the stencil script I used, but it only seems to react to alpha/non alpha.

Thanks in advance!